# How do I create a form that sends an email directly to my Gmail?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, gmail

I'm a front-end designer, so my PHP skills are pretty basic. For my personal portfolio, I want to make a contact form which sends a message straight to my gmail address. I'm having trouble making this happen. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
    if ($action=="") {
?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>Form</h2>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
<input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name"/><br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email"/><br>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
<input name="cv" checked="true"> Yes, I would like to receive ****'s resume.<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
<?php
    } else {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
        $cv=$_REQUEST['cv'];
        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) {
            echo "All fields are required. Please return to the <a href=\"\">form</a>.";
        } else {
            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
            $subject="New message sent from your form";
            $curriculum="";
            if(isset($_REQUEST['cv'])){
                $curriculum="(!) This person would like to receive my resume.";
            }
            $cmessage=$message . "\r\n\r\n" . $curriculum;
            mail("my-email@gmail.com", $subject, $cmessage, $from);
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

I'm not getting an email whenever I try filling out the form myself. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: If you're running this on localhost it's likely because you don't have a mail server set up on your computer.

Comment: #SharkofMirkwood is right, if you want to send mail. you have to place your code on some server

Comment: What OS are you on? If it's Windows, then yes, apparently you don't have a mail server set up. But if it's Linux or Mac OS (which is basically Unix anyway...) you have a mail server for free.

Anyway I suggest using a free SMTP server for development. I've been using [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/), but [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) is well known too.